# can we store a password that can't be deleted even the user clean the cache and the data

Tags: java, android

In android Settings> applications> Manage application>

When I click on any installed application that is showing me options "Clear data" and "Clear cache". so can we store a password  that can be deleted internal.

Comment: Sure you can. You can store the password on a remote server.

Comment: but i want to store it without using internet

Comment: Why would you want to store a password that persists after the user deletes the data? What if the user gives the phone to someone else after performing that operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the user delete cache and data information, you can use internal storage like XML file, always ask in your app if this exist, in case no.. you can always create them with a process and later read it. If the user delete the data... you can always create the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it on the [external storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). 
You should use some sort of encryption in this case though cause it will be easily accessible by the user or other apps.

Comment: That wouldn't be something that "can't be deleted", it just wouldn't be deleted if the user clears data or uninstalls the app.  Whether that would meet the questioner's needs in unclear.

Comment: Well, everything can be deleted.... What I understood from the question is to not be deleted automatically on clearing data/uninstall. I dont see any other way personally, anything stored in internal storage would be removed on uninstall

Comment: Yeah this is as close as you can get.  If this isn't the answer, then there is no answer.